# start a service automatically if ram is cleared by user in android

Tags: android, android-service

How to start a service automatically if Ram is cleared by user in android 
I have created one broadcastReciever and starting the service 
Sorry if I am not very cleared ..some time it is working means if  user clearing ram then still service is running but some times it is stopped and its not restarting. how to solve this problem

2) I have used alarm manager but application  getting hanged frequently so I quit alarm manager 
My code snippet are

```
public class RecieverToRestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try 
{

            Intent  _restartServiceIntent = new Intent(context,InvendisGpsLoggerActivity.class);
            _restartServiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(_restartServiceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and in android manifest file

```
<receiver   android:name="com.i.I.RecieverToRestartService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>     
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use service in your case?

Comment: @vipul Shah... Yes  because I am developing this for clients and they do't want GUI for the application and for activity GUI is necessary .Even we can hide activity GUI Using NODISPLAY Settings in manifest file but application getting hanged if we want to run the application with out GUI then service is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

In your case I haven't tested but...when you return `START_STICKY` in [`public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) this will automatically starts the service again after some time if your phone has killed it due to the low memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I have tested with START_STICKY but when I am clearing the RAM its not starting the services. I also checked documentation of android and they have mentioned that if return START_STICKY  then It will start the service .But Its not starting seems a bug in android.  90% I achieved my goal means when cell phone is restarting then service automatically starting and If I am clearing RAM then still service is running but when I clicked application ICON again and again I am clearing the RAM the service is getting killed which should not be killed . So please help me

Comment: Sorry if I am not very clear. But I am just trying to tell if I installed my app on android phone and I have restarted the phone then application is not getting killed when I am clearing RAM from task manager in phone . But if I clicked my application icon and I am clearing RAM then application getting killed this is the problem ..

Comment: can you show logcat that will be helpful to find out the problem